# Win Server 2003 R2 / QNAP Turbo NAS TS-459 Pro II - After crash: Some files can't be modified by some users

Tags: file, save, windows-server-2003, windows-server-2003-r2

a few days ago our Windows Server 2003 R2 Server / QNAP Turbo NAS TS-459 Pro II has been shutdown, because someone stubmled into the power cord (to this time, no documents had have been open). 
Now some users (for now I can't see a pattern) are having troubles with saving files (mainly .ppt) after modifying them.
Saving as a new file with an other name in the same folder is no problem.

Does anyone has an idea, what could have gone wrong?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an explorer  preview pane and the file is highlighted you will have that problem. Disable the preview pane or unselect the file.